# How to use PeoplePicker and TaxonomyPicker Controls with SPFX?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I am trying to develop a simple form using the new SharePoint Framework. The form requires PeoplePicker and TaxonomyPicker controls. I couldn't find any documentation on how to use these with the new framework?

Comment: Are you referring to the standard SharePoint PeoplePicker and TaxonomyPicker controls you would use for example in a Page Layout or a server-side Web Part?

Comment: Also - related to Waldek's question - What form tech are you using, and how does it relate to SPFx?  (We plan on doing work in this area, but I'm not aware of anything released to date)

Comment: I suspect the question is not specifically SPFx, but rather, is there a PeoplePicker and TaxonomyPicker in the UI Fabric Components that can be used.

Comment: I am using Office UI Fabric React components for other controls. But, the PeoplePicker is not complete yet and there is no TaxonomyPicker control yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Taxonomy Picker and People picker as they are available as fully featured npm modules.

```
npm install @pnp/spfx-controls-react
```

After successful installation, use the reference in your web part.

```
import { TaxonomyPicker, IPickerTerms } from "@pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/TaxonomyPicker";
```

Add the control in form as :

```
<TaxonomyPicker
  allowMultipleSelections={true}
  termsetNameOrID="Countries"
  panelTitle="Select Term"
  label="Taxonomy Picker"
  context={this.props.context}
  onChange={this.onTaxPickerChange}
  isTermSetSelectable={false}
/>
```

**[Refernce MSDN](https://sharepoint.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/TaxonomyPicker/)**

Answer (score 0):

I was referring to using TaxonomyPicker and PeoplePicker client side controls with the new SharePoint Framework. I used the TaxonomyPicker control from Office Dev PnP and managed to get this working.

I had to,

1. Get the typings for SharePoint JSOM
2. Load the [Office Dev PnP](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Components/Core.TaxonomyPicker) scripts using ModuleLoader
3. Create a React Component as a wrapper around the TaxonomyPickerControl